# Difference between AWS Community AMI RHEL and Marketplace RHEL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, rhel, amazon-ami

We have a AWS community AMI for RHEL provided by Red Hat then why one must go to AWS MarketPlace to have a RHEL subscription? What is the difference between the two; RHEL Community AMI (provided by Red Hat) v/s AWS Marketplace RHEL? I believe community AMIs are free of charge.

When AWS shows EC2 pricing for different OS like Linux (free), RHEL (chargeable), SUSE (chargeable) etc then does RHEL OS pricing includes RHEL community AMI (provided by Red Hat) or it is only applicable to AWS Marketplace RHEL subscription?

**EC2 On Demand pricing (by OS):** https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat has officially published the difference.
https://access.redhat.com/articles/3692431

Answer (score 0):

The general problem with Community AMIs is the high likelihood your instance will be infected/infested, containing one or more of data exfiltration, keystroke logging, back-door virus programs that can wake up hours or days later, run briefly, hide extremely well, and not be detectable without long-term tracking of processes and tcp traffic analysis.

Not that MarketPlace AMI cannot have such problems.  But, knowingly selling infected AMI could pose legal issues for a commercial AMI seller and void warrantees. There is nothing illegal when the Community AMI is infested as there is no warrantee, implied or otherwise.